# Implementing an interface whereby generics are based on the interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, refactoring

I am currently refactoring my code so that all important classes implement an interface (for unit testability). I came across a class that implements IComparable (non-templated); something like:

```
public MyClass : IComparable
{
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        MyClass cObj = obj as MyClass;
        if (cObj == null) { throw new ArgumentException(); }
        // etc.
    }
}
```

I'm wanting to interface it out, and use generics while I'm at it; something like this:

```
public IMyClass : IComparable<IMyClass>
{
    // Other methods here
}

public MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public CompareTo<IMyClass>(IMyClass other)
    {
        ...
    }
    // Other methods here
}
```

But then, ideally, `MyClass` should implement `IComparable<MyClass>` (and then subclasses of `MyClass` should implement `IComparable<MySubClass>`).

All of this to ask several questions:

What do you think of the approach I described? Is there a better way of doing this refactoring? Is there a point in making `MyClass` also implement `IComparable<MyClass>`, or is that pointless since we already implement `IComparable<IMyClass>`? Any pro-tips or "best"-practices I could be made aware of?

Answer (score 2):

Does it really make sense to have several objects of different types that are all comparable to each other? The language allows this, but I can count on 0 hands the number of times I've had to use it.

I'd recommend using `IClass` without being `IComparable`, and just have the derived classes implement `IComparable`.

P.S. I'm also against adding interfaces "for unit testability". If your program design calls for a factory pattern with interface-only coupling, then by all means code up that level of complexity. But don't [abuse the design](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/11/unit-testing-without-design-suicide.html) just to make your tests easier; use Moles instead.

Comment: Moles looks very interesting. Will certainly look into it; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it depends.

In your specific example, I would say it is almost always the wrong thing to do to create an unnecessary interface (`IMyClass` in this case) because it just creates work for you.  Rule of thumb: use interfaces only when more than one class implements them.  And as you point out this particular interface doesn't even accomplish the goal of making your class directly comparable.

As far as which classes should implement `IComparable`, generic or otherwise, it depends entirely on what your comparison needs are.  If comparison is always done between references to the base class, the derived class doesn't need to implement the interface as it will never be called.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your rule of thumb - the reason I'm interfacing this out is so that I can unit test classes that use it. It means I can mock this class (though arguably that means that I *do* agree with your rule of thumb, since I will be implementing it in the unit tests).

Comment: @Smashery: Your use case didn't make that clear.  That is a perfectly valid use of interfaces that "follows the rule".  :-)